# Quickly test if all element in list is the same

Tags: counting

I'm running a Monte Carlo simulation. At the end, I want to count how many simulations return a list of same element.

My problem:

```
SimulationResult = (* n x m matrix of real numbers *)
c = Count[SimulationResult,r_/;Length[Union[r]] == 1]
```

`n` is measured in the millions. `m` can go up to 50. My benchmark shows the `Count` function is taking roughly 30% of total running time when `n = 10M` and `m = 20`.

Is there anyway I can speed up the counting function?

Comment: Try DeleteDuplicates instead of Union

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If they're machine sized reals, then the following should be fast:

```
n = 10^6;
m = 50;
res = RandomReal[1, {n, m}];  (* SimulationResult *)
res[[RandomSample[Range[n], 1000]]] = ConstantArray[0., m];

cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}},
   Total[1 - Unitize[Max /@ x - Min /@ x]]];

cf[res] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.250830, 1000}  *)
```

*Variations on the body of `cf`*.  No real difference in speed, apparently, although they look like they use fewer operations.

```
Total[UnitStep[Min /@ x - Max /@ x]]  (* most elegant, perhaps *)
Length[x] - Total[Unitize[Max /@ x - Min /@ x]]
```

Comment: Thanks! You take the cheese. Hard to beat native C code.

Comment: @ Michael E2, Zoff Dino: Sorry, but in spite of much of the effort shown in this thread there's really no need for Compile. The duration of Michael E2's elegant "raw" command is (V8.0 Windows) Total[1-Unitize[Max/@res-Min/@res]]//AbsoluteTiming -> {0.3750215,1000} which is almost exactly the same as for the compiled version ({0.3710212, 1000}).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Yes, I saw the same modest improvement on packed arrays. That's because of the vectorization & optimization of such numeric functions on packed arrays does not improve with compilation, as I took Zoff Dino to imply.  The compile `cf` is faster on unpacked numeric arrays, because it seems to automatically convert the input array to a packed array faster than ``Developer`ToPackedArray``.  Simon Woods' improvement, which I briefly considered and stupidly didn't even test, is a more significant improvement since it removes one application of `Map`.

Answer (score 14):

```
Count[Equal @@@ SimulationResult, True]
Count[SameQ @@@ SimulationResult, True]
Count[Unitize[Max /@ SimulationResult - Min /@ SimulationResult], 0] (*credit: MichaelE2 *)
Count[Length /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ SimulationResult, 1]
Count[SimulationResult, _?(Equal @@ # &)]
Total[Boole[Equal @@@ SimulationResult]]
```

**Timings using @MichaelE2's setup:**

**Functions:**

```
ClearAll[a, r, c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, tf, cfr, cfi, cf2r,
        cf2i, jcfr, jcfi, functions, names];
functions = {c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, tf, cfr, cf2r, jcfr, cfi, cf2i, jcfi};
names = ToString /@ functions;

c0 = Count[#, r_ /; Length[Union[r]] == 1] &;
c1 = Count[#, r_ /; Length[DeleteDuplicates[r]] == 1] &;
c2 = Count[#, r_ /; Max[r] == Min[r]] &;
c3 = Count[#, {(a_) ..}] &;
c4 = Count[Equal @@@ #, True] &;
c5 = Count[SameQ @@@ #, True] &;
c6 = Count[Unitize[Max /@ # - Min /@ #], 0] &;
c7 = Count[#, _?(Equal @@ # &)] &;
c8 = Count[Length /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ #, 1] &;
tf = Total[Boole[Equal @@@ #]] &;
cfr = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, Total[1 - Unitize[Max /@ x - Min /@ x]]];
cfi = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 2}}, Total[1 - Unitize[Max /@ x - Min /@ x]]];
cf2r = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, 
         Length[x]-Total[Unitize[Block[{y = #}, Max[y] - Min[y]] & /@ x]]];
cf2i = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 2}}, 
         Length[x]-Total[Unitize[Block[{y = #}, Max[y] - Min[y]] & /@ x]]];
jcfr = Compile[{{reals, _Real, 2}}, 
   Block[{nC = 0, nRow, nCol, firstOfRow, row}, {nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[reals];
    Do[row = reals[[i]]; firstOfRow = row[[1]];
     Do[If[firstOfRow != row[[j]], nC++; Break[];], {j, 2, nCol}], {i,nRow}];
    nRow - nC], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
jcfi = Compile[{{reals, _Integer, 2}}, 
   Block[{nC = 0, nRow, nCol, firstOfRow, row}, {nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[reals];
    Do[row = reals[[i]]; firstOfRow = row[[1]];
     Do[If[firstOfRow != row[[j]], nC++; Break[];], {j, 2, nCol}], {i, nRow}];
    nRow - nC], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

**NOTE:** I don't have a `C` compiler installed. So, in Jacob's function are compilation target is reverted to `WVM` thereby eliminating the real advantage of this function.

**Real data:**

```
n = 10^6; m = 50;
res = RandomReal[1, {n, m}];
res[[RandomSample[Range[n], 1000]]] = ConstantArray[0., m];
nms = names[[;; -4]];
fns = functions[[;; -4]];
fns2 = fns; fns2[[-1]] = Short[fns2[[-1]], 2/3];
Grid[Thread[{nms, fns2, First@AbsoluteTiming[#[res]] & /@ fns}]]
```

[image]

**Integer data:**

```
n = 10^6; m = 50;
res = RandomInteger[100, {n, m}];
res[[RandomSample[Range[n], 1000]]] = ConstantArray[0, m];
nms = Join[names[[;; -7]], names[[-3 ;;]]];
fns = Join[functions[[;; -7]], functions[[-3 ;;]]];
fns2 = fns; fns2[[-1]] = Short[fns2[[-1]], 2/3];
Grid[Thread[{nms, fns2, First@AbsoluteTiming[#[res]] & /@ fns}]]
```

[image]

Comment: For the curious, the reason `cf` is slower on an integer array is that the numbers of type `Integer` are first converted to `Real`.  The question specified real numbers, but for integers, `cf` should be defined `Compile[{{x, _Integer, 2}}, ...]`.  For either type, the uncompiled function `Total[1 - Unitize[Max /@ # - Min /@ #]]&` is only slightly slower than the compiled function on packed arrays.  One could also define a function that would call the appropriate type compiled function depending on the input.

Comment: Would you consider including my answer?

Comment: @Jacob, just added your and Simon's answers.

Comment: @Jacob, since i don't have a C compiler installed, the timing numbers are actually for default compilation target `WVM`:(

Comment: @kguler Alright, I guess it is fine this way. I edited my own answer with the comparison in the `CompilationTarget->"C"` case. Thank you for including me :).

Answer (score 13):

Funnily enough, this is pretty fast for a top-level code:

```
Count[SimulationResult, {(a_) ..}]
```

Answer (score 6):

I can shave about 15% off Michael E2's time with slight tweaks to the compiled code:

```
cf2 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, 
  Length[x] - Total[Unitize[Block[{y = #}, Max[y] - Min[y]] & /@ x]]];
```

Comment: +1. Nice.  I thought I considered trying something like this but stupidly dismissed it.  Probably didn't like introducing a new variable. But getting rid of a `Map` now seems an obvious thing to try.

Answer (score 5):

The code in this answer is about 4x faster than code in other answers, and 3x if you improve other answers by setting `CompilationTarget-> "C"`.

**My function**

Here is my function

```
jacobCCf =
 Compile[
  {{reals, _Real, 2}},
  Block[
   {nC = 0, nRow, nCol, firstOfRow, row}
   ,
   {nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[reals];
   Do[
    row = reals[[i]];
    firstOfRow = row[[1]];
    Do[
     If[firstOfRow !=  row[[j]]
      ,
      nC++; Break[];
      ]
     ,
     {j, 2, nCol}
     ]
    ,
    {i, nRow}
    ];
   nRow - nC
   ]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

**Setting up the comparison**

Definitions for comparison, especially functions by others

```
jacobWVMCf =
  Compile[
   {{reals, _Real, 2}},
   Block[
    {nC = 0, nRow, nCol, firstOfRow}
    ,
    {nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[reals];
    Do[

     firstOfRow = reals[[i, 1]];
     Do[
      If[firstOfRow !=  reals[[i, j]]
       ,
       nC++; Break[];
       ]
      ,
      {j, 2, nCol}
      ]
     ,
     {i, nRow}
     ];
    nRow - nC
    ]
   ];
cfr = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, 
   Total[1 - Unitize[Max /@ x - Min /@ x]]];
cf2 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, 
   Length[x] - Total[Unitize[Block[{y = #}, Max[y] - Min[y]] & /@ x]]];
cfrC = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, 
   Total[1 - Unitize[Max /@ x - Min /@ x]], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
cf2C = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, 
   Length[x] - 
    Total[Unitize[Block[{y = #}, Max[y] - Min[y]] & /@ x]], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Functions for comparing and formatting timings

```
timing = Function[Null, First@Timing@#, HoldAll];
timingAndName = 
  Function[Null, {timing@#, ToString@Unevaluated@#}, HoldAll];
timingsAndNamesTable = 
  Function[Null, 
   TableForm[timingAndName /@ Unevaluated[{##}], 
    TableHeadings -> {None, {"Timings", "Code executed"}}], HoldAll];

formattedTimingsAndComparison = 
  Function[Null, 
   Block[{timingTable}, timingTable = timingsAndNamesTable@##;
    Column[{StringForm["Comparison for n = ``", n], timingTable, 
      If[SameQ @@ resultNames, "results are equal", 
       Row[{"results are ", Style["not ", Bold], "equal"}]]}, 
     Spacings -> 2]], HoldAll];

compare[] := 
 ReplacePart[
  List @@
   MapIndexed[
    Function[Null, Join[resultNames[[# ;; # &@First@#2]], Hold@#@res],
      HoldAll],
    funcNames
    ]
  ,
  {0 -> formattedTimingsAndComparison, {_, 0} -> Set}
  ]
```

**Actual comparison**

Now

```
n = 10^6; m = 50;
res = RandomReal[1, {n, m}];
res[[RandomSample[Range[n], 1000]]] = ConstantArray[0., m];

resultNames = Hold[jacobN, michaelCN, simonCN, jacobWVMN, michaelN, simonN];
funcNames = Hold[jacobCCf, cfrC, cf2C, jacobWVMCf, cfr, cf2];
compare[]
```

gives

> Comparison for n = 1000000
>
> ```
> "Timings"   "Code executed"
> --------------------------------
> 0.083284    jacobN = jacobCCf[res]
> 0.305532    michaelCN = cfrC[res]
> 0.224818    simonCN = cf2C[res]
> 0.302028    jacobWVMN = jacobWVMCf[res]
> 0.427718    michaelN = cfr[res]
> 0.314330    simonN = cf2[res]
> ```
>
> results are equal

Answer (score 1):

not sure about this but try it.

```
Count[SimulationResult, r_ /; Max[r] == Min[r]]
```